# Simple jQuery selector isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to parse this HTML:

```
<tr id="a">
    <td class="classA">
        <span class="classB">Toronto</span>
    </td>
    <td class="classC">
        <span class="classD">Winnipeg</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="b">
    <td class="classA">
        <span class="classB">Montreal</span>
    </td>
    <td class="classC">
        <span class="classD">Calgary</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have a variable `team`. I want to find the `<span>` that contains `team`. Then I want to navigate up to the `<tr>` and pull the `id` from it.

I tried:

```
var team = "Toronto";
var id = $("span:contains(" + team + ")").parent().parent().attr('id');
```

But it comes back undefined. I know the selector is right, because `$("span:contains(" + team + ")").attr('class')` comes back with `classB`. So I can't figure out what's wrong with my query. Can anyone help?

Edit: Here's the [JSFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/BgMSd/1/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `html` is **invalid** but your *selector is correct*, you need to put `tr` in `table` tag for valid html. You better use `closest("tr")` instead of `.parent().parent()`

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/BgMSd/2/)

```
<table>
    <tr id="a">
        <td class="classA"> <span class="classB">Toronto</span>

        </td>
        <td class="classC"> <span class="classD">Winnipeg</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
        <td class="classA"> <span class="classB">Montreal</span>

        </td>
        <td class="classC"> <span class="classD">Calgary</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working becuase the browser's automatically fixing your HTML. You can't have a TR without a table so it's just throwing it away. All that's actually part of the DOM by the time your JavaScript runs is the spans.

Wrap it in a `<table>` and your code will work. Even better wrap it in `<table><tbody>` because the browser will still be making a tbody for you with just a table & that might cause confusion next (If you look at the parent of the TR).

Answer (score 0):

Currently your HTML markup is invalid, you need to wrap `<tr>` element inside `<table>`:

```
<table>
    <tr id="a">
        <td class="classA"> <span class="classB">Toronto</span>

        </td>
        <td class="classC"> <span class="classD">Winnipeg</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="b">
        <td class="classA"> <span class="classB">Montreal</span>

        </td>
        <td class="classC"> <span class="classD">Calgary</span>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Also, it's better to use `.closest()` as well as `.prop()` instead of `.parent()` and `.attr()`

```
var id = $("span:contains(" + team + ")").closest('tr').prop('id');
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B498x/)**

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
var id = $("span:contains(" + team + ")").parent('td').parent('tr').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works good.Just wrap your code into `<table></table>`

HTML

```
<table>
<tr id="a">
    <td class="classA">
        <span class="classB">Toronto</span>
    </td>
    <td class="classC">
        <span class="classD">Winnipeg</span>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr id="b">
    <td class="classA">
        <span class="classB">Montreal</span>
    </td>
    <td class="classC">
        <span class="classD">Calgary</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Script

```
var team = "Toronto";
var id = $("span:contains(" + team + ")").closest('tr').prop('id');
console.log(id)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7Eh7L/

Better use `closest()`

```
$("span:contains(" + team + ")").closest('tr').prop('id');
```